# How do I select an OID for my MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, oid, mib

I've been trying to attach an OID to run a specific script for sometime and at this point I think the culprit is my bad MIB.

I've corrected my MIB but I'm curious about the OID i'm trying to use.

Currently I am trying to use the `.1.3.6.1.4.1.214` tree.  The `214` is mapped to University of Wisconsin - Madison.  While I'm not at Madison, I am in the UW system.

Basically what I'm asking is, what is stopping me from using the University of Wisconsin - Madison enterprise OID?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing stopping you from using another enterprise's OIDs, but that would be inconsiderate. You're supposed to [request your own Private Enterprise Number](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) and use that in building your OIDs/MIBs.

Comment: Alright cool! Seeing as how I'm just doing this for a final project, I'll just use theirs.  If anything ever possesses me to do SNMP again, I'll request my own.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Make sure you don't collide with any OIDs that UW is already using. http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers lists contact details for the person responsible for the enterprise number. You should contact them and ask for a chunk of the space assigned to UW.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing - In the same way that you can also use 8.8.8.8 as your IP if you don't connect to the internet. It's just a convention to prevent clashes between everyone saying 'ok .1 is mine!'

If you want to be able access their oids and yours together, you'll obviously run into issues if you don't play nicely.